# JavaScript Math (parameter passing, arrays, and the "apply" method)

Tags: javascript

1) Why does the `function smallest` fail? I think it conforms to the example in the Mozilla documentation https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/min, which says

```
 function getMin(x,y) {  //from Mozilla documentation
   return Math.min(x,y)
}



function smallest(array){ //my own experimentation with Resig`s example
  return Math.min(array);
}
function largest(array){      //from John Resig`s learning advanced JavaScript #41
  return Math.max.apply( Math, array );
}
assert(smallest([0, 1, 2, 3]) == 0, "Locate the smallest value.");
assert(largest([0, 1, 2, 3]) == 3, "Locate the largest value.");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Math.min` and `Math.max` takes any number of numbers, as arguments. Your `smallest` is trying to pass an array, not numbers.

The use of `apply` (as in `largest` in your example) pastes the elements of the array as arguments.

Answer (score 5):

The "Math.min()" function can take an arbitrary number of arguments. However, passing a single array to the function is just passing in **one** argument, not several.  That single argument is the array itself. Arrays, you will recall, are first-rate values.

That's the whole point of the "apply" function that's available on every function. It is used to invoke the function and pass it an argument list composed of entries in an array instance. When you do this:

```
var array = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ];
someFunction.apply(irrelevant, array);
```

that's like calling:

```
someFunction(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
```

(The "irrelevant" argument is what's to be used as the `this` value in the function call.)

Comment: I think you meant "first-class", not "first-rate". :-)

Comment: Well to me they're both "first class" **and** "first rate" :-)

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't conform to the example. The []'s in the documentation are optional indicators, not array delimiters.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
function smallest(array) { return Math.min.apply(Math, array); }
```

It won't work when passed as an array because `min` converts its arguments to numbers before comparing.  Trying to convert an array to a number will, unless the array contains a single element that looks like a number, produce `NaN`.

So

```
Math.min([3]) === 3
Math.min('3') === 3
```

but

```
isNaN(Math.min([3, 4]))  // because,
isNaN(Math.min('3,4'))  // which is the same as
isNaN(Math.min(+'3,4'))  // which is equivalent to
isNaN(Math.min(NaN))
```

Comment: I know the example you provide works, but I`m wondering why (for learning purposes) why my example, which seems to confirm to the Mozilla example, doesn`t.

Comment: Well, you should explain to the OP why the `apply` is necessary (he's already worked out that it's necessary: see `largest`).

Answer (score 1):

`.apply( object, array )` is the correct syntax to unpack an array into an argument list. Just passing an array to a function that converts all arguments to a number isn't useful, since it will only see NaN.

Answer (score 1):

**apply** passes the array to Math.min as an arguments object-
Math.min(a,b,c,d,e)

smallest is passing the whole array as the first agument-

Math.min(x)
and it really has nothing to compare it to.